# How can I copy coupon taxonomy terms in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My goal here is to assign categories to coupons and then bulk duplicate them **with the categories assigned**.

**In order to assign categories**, I'm using a plugin called Woocommerce Coupons by Categories and Tags which creates a new taxonomy `coupon_category` for the coupon:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'woocommerce_coupons_by_categories_and_tags' ) ) {
class woocommerce_coupons_by_categories_and_tags {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init',                                   array( $this, 'wct_create_category' ) );
        
        add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_coupon_columns',        array( $this, 'wct_custom_taxonomy_columns' ) );
        add_action( 'manage_shop_coupon_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'wct_custom_taxonomy_content' ), 10, 2 );
        
        add_action( 'admin_menu',                             array( $this, 'wct_add_coupon_category_admin_submenu' ) );
        add_filter( 'parent_file',                            array( $this, 'wct_make_menu_active' ) ); 
    }
    
    //Register custom taxonomy called Coupon categories 
    public function wct_create_category() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'              => __( 'Coupon categories', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Category', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'menu_name'         => _x( 'Categories', 'Admin menu name', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Coupon categories', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All categories', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent category', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent category:', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit coupon category', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update category', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add new coupon category', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New category name', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
            'not_found'         => __( 'No categories found', 'woocommerce-coupon-taxonomy' ),
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'coupon_category', array('shop_coupon'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'coupon_category' ),
        ) );
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'coupon_category', 'shop_coupon' );
    }
```

**To duplicate the coupons**, I'm using another plugin called Coupon Bulker, which works getting the information from an original coupon and making copies of it with newly generated codes.

The problem here is that the copies won't take into account the custom taxonomy.

This plugin is a bit bigger, but looking well into the files it looks like the automatically generated coupons are created using the piece of code here below.

```
    /**
        * Create a coupon programmatically
        */
        $coupon_code = $this->generate_coupon_code($code_prefix); // Code
        $gen_codes[] = $coupon_code;
        
        $coupon = array(
        'post_title' => $coupon_code,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => get_post_field( 'post_author', $coupon_id ),
        'post_type' => 'shop_coupon');


        //Create new coupon
        $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );
        $new_coupon = new WC_Coupon($new_coupon_id);

        // Update its meta
        //general
        $new_coupon->set_discount_type($orig_coupon->get_discount_type());
        $new_coupon->set_amount($orig_coupon->get_amount());
        $new_coupon->set_free_shipping($orig_coupon->get_free_shipping() );
        $new_coupon->set_date_expires($orig_coupon->get_date_expires() );

        //use limits
        $new_coupon->set_individual_use($orig_coupon->get_individual_use());
        $new_coupon->set_product_ids($orig_coupon->get_product_ids());
        $new_coupon->set_excluded_product_ids($orig_coupon->get_excluded_product_ids());
        $new_coupon->set_minimum_amount($orig_coupon->get_maximum_amount());
        $new_coupon->set_maximum_amount($orig_coupon->get_maximum_amount());

        //usage limits
        $new_coupon->set_usage_limit($orig_coupon->get_usage_limit() );
        $new_coupon->set_usage_limit_per_user($orig_coupon->get_usage_limit_per_user());
        $new_coupon->set_limit_usage_to_x_items($orig_coupon->get_limit_usage_to_x_items());

        // SAVE the coupon
        $new_coupon->save();
    }
```

I have tried adding the custom meta before the `$new_coupon->save();` line like this:

```
//COUPON CATEGORY
        
        $new_coupon->set_meta_data($orig_coupon->get_meta_data(coupon_category));
```

This above does nothing, and I've tried also long shots like `$new_coupon->set_coupon_category($orig_coupon->get_coupon_category() );` which of course give error.

I'm confident (maybe?) that if I can properly select the custom meta data and put it in the code I can make the Coupon Bulker plugin to duplicate the plugin with the category assigned.

But how do I know what is the proper meta and how to call it?

---

*Edit:*
I'm adding this snapshot to see what I'm trying to achieve here.
The columns on the right "Categorías" and "Etiquetas" (Categories and tags) are custom.

The post seen below is the original and the above is the copy. As you can see, all the information is successfully copied except the data in the custom columns.

Coupon type is copied because of the line `$new_coupon->set_discount_type($orig_coupon->get_discount_type());`

Coupon amount is copied because of the line `$new_coupon->set_amount($orig_coupon->get_amount());`

And so on.

The line to copy the category (and tag at this point) is missing and it's what I'm trying to find.

[image: Visual Example]

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L377 as you can see set_meta_data() requires id key value . Try using update_meta_data() . Also what is coupon_category ? To know what is happening use debug then you will know is there any data returned or not.

Comment: Thank you @MartinMirchev . I've tried `$new_coupon->update_meta_data($orig_coupon->get_meta_data());` but I'm getting an error.

coupon_category I believe it is the slug of the taxonomy created even though perhaps it should not be necessary to include it.

I'll keep trying, thank you again for the hints!

Comment: What is missing in your question is the `$orig_coupon` part, how this is added/created. because this object is used, when creating `$new_coupon` but it is not specified. 
Assuming `$orig_coupon` (shop_coupon) is just a post type, you can use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), 
which retrieves the terms of the taxonomy associated with the post.

Comment: Thank you @7uc1f3r . I've found that here:

`// Get an instance of WC_Coupon object in an array(necessary to use WC_Coupon methods)
        $orig_coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);`

And there's all it is. Using get_the terms() is throwing an object error. I'm assuming it is because it is not a method in WC_Coupon based on this: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Coupon.html ?

Comment: @vsilvestre22 
see how [this is applied](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woo-coupons-by-categories-and-tags/tags/1.1/woocommerce-coupons-category-tag.php#L93) (line 93 - category or line 105 - tag) in the plugin you already use. `$post_id` becomes `$orig_coupon->get_id()`

Comment: Thans @7uc1f3r . I see that but I'm not sure that I follow... I've tried:

`$new_coupon->get_the_terms($orig_coupon->get_id());` This give object error. Creates a new coupon but none of the data is copied.

`$new_coupon->set_meta_data($orig_coupon->get_id());` This works "well", but has no effect. The new coupon copies all the data except for the categories and tags.

I keep trying alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to get the original coupon object ID.

One idea on how you can get the original coupon object id is using the original coupon code as follows:

```
//Retrieve the original coupon ID
$coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($original_coupon_code, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
$coupon_id       = $coupon_post_obj->ID;
```

Once you get the original coupon ID, then its time to get the terms associated with that ID using wp_get_object_terms

```
//Get the terms of the original coupon ID
$terms_of_existing_coupon = wp_get_object_terms( $coupon_id, 'coupon_category' )
```

You have the terms (categories) now. So we just need to assign them to new coupon id using this:

```
//Set the terms to the new coupon ID
 wp_set_object_terms($new_coupon_id, $terms_of_existing_coupon,'coupon_category');
```

You can run all these after the new coupon gets saved i.e after `$new_coupon->save();` function, because that is when you will also get the new coupon object ID.

In summary, the solution is to get the terms of existing coupon id and then set the same terms to new coupon id using `wp_get_object_terms` and `wp_set_object_terms` which are wp core functions.

Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I understand the principle and appreciate the help. It's not working as expected but you got me almost there:

I've put these lines after `$new_coupon->save();` as you said, changing `$original_coupon_code` with `$orig_coupon` which is the variable used to retrieve the original coupon.

The result is that the duplicated coupon gets the "coupon_category" taxanomy but instead of copying the original category it creates a new (empty) one.

This is OK because I can always give a name to the empty category recently created, but I'm still hoping to get the original category.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that I had to change `wp_get_object_terms` with `get_terms` for this to happen. With `wp_get_object_terms` nothing happens (the category is not copied nor even created new one).